# Proper date format

Tags: cocoa

I have used date picker in my iPad App but the output of date is coming as

> 2011-03-07 06:07:03 +0000

Is there any way to format the time? The above time output is shown when i gave input time as 11:35 AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There's also a [date formatting guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).